# Cannot get anything in https protocol with curl, httparty or net::http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, https, httparty

I am having trouble to get anything using https.

I can't fetch anything like:

```
curl -k https://graph.facebook.com
```

or

```
uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/davidarturo')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

I get:

```
error: EOFError: end of file reached
```

Also there is no luck with httparty and https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use 'https' protocol, you must explicitly tell about it in case of using `net/http` library:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/davidarturo')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'

http.start do |h|
  response = h.request Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  puts response.body if Net::HTTPSuccess
end
```